# Can 'en' replace a person?

Tags: pronoms, en

This is an excerpt from an email:

> Nous allons également, comme au semestre 1, réduire la durée de ces
> Temps experts. Nous utiliserons ce fonctionnement jusqu'à nouvel ordre
> de ma part, sans exclure des modifications liées à l'évolution du
> covid. Vous en serez informés.
>
> **Restant disponible si vous en avez besoin.**

I think that 'en' replaces 'de moi' (i.e. si vous avez besoin de moi). If so, can the pronoun 'en' replace a person (or a proper name)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, *en* doesn't replace replace *de moi*, although the meaning wouldn't be significantly different.

***En*** is there to replace the fact of being available:

> Restant disponible si vous avez besoin que nous soyons disponibles.

> Restant disponible si vous avez besoin de notre disponibilité.

Anyway, there are certainly cases where *en* can refer to a person:

> — J'ai deux filles.
> — Moi, j'**en** ai une.

Answer (score 1):

In almost all cases, « en » can replace only an inanimate or a non-human animate.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en)) Rem. Quelle que soit sa forme, l'antécédent relève normalement de l'inanimé ou de l'animé non hum. (animaux); plus rarement en peut représenter un subst. désignant un animé hum.

Your deduction is not correct, that is "en" does not replace "de moi".

In this case "en" replaces the subject being introduced. This is attested in the case of adverbials (comp. circ.)

([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en)) C'est une affaire **majeure** pour notre commerce. Je vous en ai écrit par le dernier courrier (Chateaubr., Congr. Vérone,t. 2, 1838, p. 102).
(*C'est une affaire majeure pour notre commerce. Je vous  ai écrit *à propos de cela* par le dernier courrier.*)

In this sentence the subject is "the **importance** of a business deal in a given commercial activity".

In the case of "Restant disponible si vous en avez besoin" the only way out is to consider that a subject is the antecedent, and that  subject is that of the availability of that person; however, such a syntax is apparently not attested anywhere ("en" is a "COI" here, not a "comp. circ.)"; personally, I am not familiar with this form and would not use it.

- Restant disponible si vous avez besoin de cette disponibilité (*but that is rather awkward, and would not be said in French*)

I'd rather say this.

- Restant disponible, au cas où vous auriez besoin de moi.